# Can you use Athena ODBC/JDBC to return the S3 location of results?

Tags: r, amazon-athena

I've been using the [metis](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/metis) package to run Athena queries via R.  While this is great for small queries, there still does not seem to be a viable solution for queries with very large return datasets (10's of thousands of rows, for example). However, when running these same queries in the AWS console, it is fast/straightforward to use the download link to obtain the CSV file of the query result.

This got me thinking: is there a mechanism for sending the query via R but returning/obtaining the `S3://` bucket location where the query results live  instead of the normal results object?

Comment: Looks like the kernel of an ideal solution is beginning here: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1733206

Comment: New hrbrmstr package for using async retrieval: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/roto.athena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above you could investigate the [`RAthena`](https://github.com/DyfanJones/RAthena) and [`noctua`](https://github.com/DyfanJones/noctua) packages.

These packages connect to AWS Athena using AWS SDK's as their drivers. What this means is that they will also download the data from S3 in as similar method that is mentioned by @Zerodf. They both use data.table to load the data into R so they are pretty quick. Also you can get to Query Execution ID if required for some reason.

Here is an example of how to use the packages:

## RAthena

Create a connection to AWS Athena, for more information around how to connect please look at: [dbConnect](https://dyfanjones.github.io/RAthena/reference/dbConnect-AthenaDriver-method.html)

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RAthena::athena())
```

Example in how to query Athena:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "select * from sampledb.elb_logs")
```

How to access the Query ID:

```
res <- dbSendQuery(con,  "select * from sampledb.elb_logs")

sprintf("%s%s.csv",res@connection@info$s3_staging, res@info$QueryExecutionId)
```

## noctua

Create a connection to AWS Athena, for more information around how to connect please look at: [dbConnect](https://dyfanjones.github.io/noctua/reference/dbConnect-AthenaDriver-method.html)

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(noctua::athena())
```

Example in how to query Athena:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "select * from sampledb.elb_logs")
```

How to access the Query ID:

```
res <- dbSendQuery(con,  "select * from sampledb.elb_logs")

sprintf("%s%s.csv",res@connection@info$s3_staging, res@info$QueryExecutionId)
```

## Sum up

These packages should do what you are looking for however as they download the data from the query output in s3 I don't believe you will need to go to the query execution ID to do the same process.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [Cloudyr Project](https://github.com/cloudyr/).  They have a [package](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.signature) that handles creating the signature requests for the AWS API.  Then you can fire off a query, poll AWS until the query finishes (using the QueryExecutionID), and use [aws.s3](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3) to download the result set.

You can also use [system()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) to use [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) commands to execute a query, wait for the results, and download the results.

For example: You could run the following commands on the command line to get the results of a query.

`$ aws athena start-query-execution --query-string "select count(*) from test_null_unquoted" --execution-context Database=stackoverflow --result-configuration OutputLocation=s3://SOMEBUCKET/ --output text
XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`

Once you get the `query-execution-id`, then you can check on the results.

`$ aws athena get-query-execution --query-execution-id=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX --output text
QUERYEXECUTION  select count(*) from test_null_unquoted XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
QUERYEXECUTIONCONTEXT   stackoverflow
RESULTCONFIGURATION     s3://SOMEBUCKET/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX.csv
STATISTICS      104     1403
STATUS  1528809056.658  SUCCEEDED       1528809054.945`

Once the query succeeds, you can download the data.

`$ aws s3 cp s3://stack-exchange/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX.csv`

**Edit:**
You can even turn those commands into a one liner (Bash example here), but I'm sure you could do the same thing in powershell.

`` $ eid=`aws athena start-query-execution --query-string "select count(*) from test_null_unquoted" --query-execution-context Database=SOMEDATABASE--result-configuration OutputLocation=s3://SOMEBUCKET/ --output text --output text` && until aws athena get-query-execution --query-execution-id=$eid --output text | grep "SUCCEEDE
D"; do sleep 10 | echo "waiting..."; done && aws s3 cp s3://SOMEBUCKET/$eid.csv . && unset eid ``

Comment: thanks @zerodf. this is great. My idea solution would be within the context of the JDBC driver so let me give it another day or two to see if such an answer pops up. otherwise I will accept this answer.

Comment: This concept is used in the packages [`RAthena`](https://github.com/DyfanJones/RAthena) and [`noctua`](https://github.com/DyfanJones/noctua). The packages use python's Boto3 and R paws SDKs into amazon to create a DBI interface into Athena.  If you want the Athena Query ID to be surfaced within these packages please raise a issue ticket on the linked githubs.